# Passing a generic class into function at compile time

Tags: c#, generics

Would the following code work in c#?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Related_Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void do_something<T>(T t)
    {
        string n = t.Name;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo f = new Foo();

        do_something(f);
    }
}
```

In .Net 4 the compiler is complaining:

'T' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well, since you tried it and got a compiler error clearly the answer is "no".  Thus you have answered your own question, the following code will not work.  Perhaps you should explain what you want to do and ask how to accomplish that goal, rather than asking a question you have already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a constrain on the generic type `T` - otherwise how should compiler know about it?

Make an `Ifoo` and then

```
do_something<T>(T t) where T : IFoo  

interface IFoo
{
    string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this code will not work in C#, because there is nothing that constraints the type `T` to have a property called `Name`. Templates in C# does not work the same way as in C++, where the compiler can expand them at compile time and verify that certain members that are used actually exists.

To make it work you could add a constraint that `T` must be of a type that has a property called name. For example create an interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

and have your classes implement this interface.

Then add the constraint to your method as follows:

```
static void do_something<T>(T t) where T : IFoo
{
    string n = t.Name;
}
```

If all your classes have a common base class that has a property `Name`, such as if `Related_Foo` was derived from `Foo` you could constrain it to the class type instead, same syntax:

```
static void do_something<T>(T t) where T : Foo
{
    string n = t.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If do_something should always take Foo or anything derived from Foo (rather than just always have a Property called Name), you could do this:

```
 static void do_something<T>(T t) where T : Foo
 {
      string n = t.Name;
 }
```

This is constraining the Type passed in to be of Type Foo or any types derived from it.